# Deleting .jar files using VB Script

Tags: file-io, vbscript, jar

I am very new to VB Script and I want to use it to delete .jar files (and only .jar files) in a folder. Through some research, I have found that I can use `Set deleteJar = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` to delete files. But these are simple .txt files in the examples I've seen. How would I write it so that it only delete .jar files in the folder (and all of its subfolders as well)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could certainly use a `FileSystemObject` and a recursive function to find all `JAR` files and delete them, it'd be simpler to just use an existing tool: the `del` command.

```
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run "%comspec% /c del /s c:\myfolder\*.jar", 0, True
End With
```

Details:

`%comspec%` will launch a command prompt

`/c` will close the command prompt upon completion

`del` is the command to delete files

`/s` will cause `del` to search recursively within a folder

`c:\myfolder\*.jar` is the file spec to match (starting folder and type of file to search for)

`0` is the 2nd param to `Run` and causes the command prompt window to remain hidden

`True` is the 3rd param to `Run` and prevents VBScript from continuing until the command completes (AKA, a "synchronous" call)